# Renaming a directory in gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

I'm using `gulp-rename` to rename a directory as follows:

```
gulp.task('vendor-rename-pre', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/vendor')
    .pipe(rename('vendor-dev'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});
```

However, it essentially ends up creating a new, empty directory called `vendor-dev` instead of renaming `vendor`. `vendor` is left as is.

So, how can I actually rename a directory using gulp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing Gulp-specific about renaming a file on disk. You can just use the standard Node.js [`fs.rename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) function:

```
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('vendor-rename-pre', function(done) {
  fs.rename('src/vendor', 'src/vendor-dev', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question you can do below to use `gulp-rename` to rename the file

```
gulp.task('vendor-rename-pre', function () {
  return gulp.src("./app/vendor")
    .pipe(rename("./vendor-dev"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./app"));
});
```

The only caveat here is that the old file will remain in the same location

Comment: Right, so it's more of a copy instead of rename :) ... but I guess that can be address with `del`